# Archiving every four files in a folder to a zip-file with a Windows batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop, zip, shapes

I have a folder with Esri Shapes. Every Shape consists of 4 seperate files (.dbf, .prj, .shp, .shx). I want every shape archived in a seperate .zip file. Also, I want this .zip-file to have the same name as the shape it contains.

For example if I have the following files:

- Test1.dbf
- Test1.prj
- Test1.shp
- Test1.shx
- Test2.dbf
- Test2.prj
- Test2.shp
- Test2.shx

Then I want these files archived as below:

- Test1.zip:

  - Test1.dbf
  - Test1.prj
  - Test1.shp
  - Test1.shx
- Test2.zip:

  - Test2.dbf
  - Test2.prj
  - Test2.shp
  - Test2.shx

So I Reckoned this could be done with a batch-file and a FOR-loop. However, I don't know much about the code language needed to write a batch-file. I found some code elsewhere on Stackoverflow, but it returns only the .shp-files in the resulting .zip-files.

For example I get:

- Test1.zip:

  - Test1.shp
- Test2.zip:

  - Test2.shp

This code is:

```
@ECHO ON

SET SourceDir=sourcefolder
SET DestDir=destinationfolder

CD /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%"') DO (
7z.exe a "%DestDir%\%%~NF.zip" "%SourceDir%\%%~NXF"
)
EXIT
```

Can someone tell me how to adjust this so to get all 4 components per shape in a single .zip-file?

Comment: instead of `%%~NXF` you want `%%~NF.*`

Comment: Nice! That worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: If I got it right, together with @Stephan's suggestion, each archive is first created and then reopened for another three times; therefore I would change the `dir` command to `dir /B /A:-D "%SourceDir%\*.prj"`, so no archive becomes reopened any more...

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl ! This saves me some time again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Stephan and aschipfl, the code should look like this:

```
@ECHO ON

SET SourceDir=SourceFolder
SET DestDir=DestinationFolder

CD /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('dir /B /A:-D "%SourceDir%\*.prj"') DO (
    7z.exe a "%DestDir%\%%~NF.zip" "%SourceDir%\%%~NF.*"
)
EXIT
```

The difference is found in the dir-command within the FOR-loop.